# How to 'edit page' with react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I am trying to make an edit profile page with react native. For example, a user wants to change his/her username so should go to the profile edit page. But after fetch the data from the database, I can't update the data.
I tried to use  TextInput value prop. But if don't click it, it just sends null value. You can see my codes below.

```
   <View >
        <TextInput
          placeholder='Adres'
          placeholderTextColor='#808e9b'
          style={styles.biginput}
          multiline={true}
          numberOfLines={50}
          value={this.state.address} 
          onChangeText={Address => this.setState({ Address })}
        />
      </View>
```

And i tried to use like below. But it sends null again

```
       <View >

        <TextInput
          placeholder='İl'
          placeholderTextColor='#808e9b'
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={City => this.setState({ City })}
        >
          {this.state.city} 
        </TextInput>
      </View>
```

What should i do update the data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not set the initial values when fetching the data from the server. Because of this if the user does not touch textInput, values are not set so they are null. When fetching the data set your states first.